# Use FileToBlob() in ImageMagick

Tags: c, imagemagick

I'm attempting to read a file using the ImageMagick C API. For reasons I need to read it as a blob (it could be stdin, and I need to read it twice). Below is a code snippet I'm using to read the file.

```
size_t blob_length = 0;
ExceptionInfo blob_exception;
printf("about to read blob\n");
void *blob = FileToBlob(filename, 99999999, &blob_length, &blob_exception);
printf("read blob: %ld\n", blob_length);
```

If filename is a normal filename, things seem to work. If filename is the special value "-" (meaning, read stdin), I get an error:

```
about to read blob
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

gdb shows the following stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff60a14dc in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6051998 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff603b53d in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff609567e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff60ab26c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff60af00c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff60afd12 in realloc () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff7916924 in ResizeMagickMemory () from /usr/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.10
#8  0x00007ffff7845d4c in FileToBlob () from /usr/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.10
#9  0x0000555555556fa5 in scan_image (filename=filename@entry=0x7fffffffe259 "-")
    at zbarimg/zbarimg.c:187
#10 0x0000555555556840 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffde28) at zbarimg/zbarimg.c:480
```

I'm using ImageMagick 7.1.0-47 Q16-HDRI. Checking an [online version](https://imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/blob_8c_source.html) of the source, I'm a little confused since I see only calls to `ResizeQuantumMemory`, not `ResizeMagickMemory`.

I assume the error is on my end (I'm a major C newbie) but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: I slightly simplified the program (cut it down to just the 5-10 lines needed to reproduce)

```
//gcc -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-7 -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -lMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI magick.c
#include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>

static int scan_image(const char *filename)
{
    size_t blob_length = 0;
    ExceptionInfo blob_exception;
    printf("about to read blob\n"); 
    void *blob = FileToBlob(filename, 99999999, &blob_length, &blob_exception);
    printf("read blob: %ld\n", blob_length); 
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    scan_image("-");
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output

```
==947372== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==947372== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==947372== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==947372== Command: ./a.out
==947372== 
about to read blob
==947372== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==947372==    at 0x4E1EDF1: read (read.c:26)
==947372==    by 0x4A17D72: UnknownInlinedFun (unistd.h:38)
==947372==    by 0x4A17D72: FileToBlob (blob.c:1473)
==947372==    by 0x1091B3: scan_image (in /home/zachary/a.out)
==947372==    by 0x109207: main (in /home/zachary/a.out)
==947372==  Address 0x7a338b1 is 0 bytes after a block of size 81,921 alloc'd
==947372==    at 0x4846CC3: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==947372==    by 0x4AE8923: ResizeMagickMemory (memory.c:1407)
==947372==    by 0x4A17D4B: FileToBlob (blob.c:1485)
==947372==    by 0x1091B3: scan_image (in /home/zachary/a.out)
==947372==    by 0x109207: main (in /home/zachary/a.out)
==947372== 
--947372-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 7 (SIGBUS) - exiting
--947372-- si_code=128;  Faulting address: 0x0;  sp: 0x1002ca9e40

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

host stacktrace:
==947372==    at 0x5804D09B: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==947372==    by 0x580056B2: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==947372==    by 0x5809B33D: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==947372==    by 0x580E40C0: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 947372)
==947372==    at 0x4846CC3: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==947372==    by 0x4AE8923: ResizeMagickMemory (memory.c:1407)
==947372==    by 0x4A17D4B: FileToBlob (blob.c:1485)
==947372==    by 0x1091B3: scan_image (in /home/zachary/a.out)
==947372==    by 0x109207: main (in /home/zachary/a.out)
client stack range: [0x1FFEFFA000 0x1FFF000FFF] client SP: 0x1FFEFFFC30
valgrind stack range: [0x1002BAA000 0x1002CA9FFF] top usage: 17872 of 1048576
```

Comment: You can't read stdin twice, right?

Comment: The stack trace doesn't tell you what  (in FileToBlob) calls `ResizeMagickMemory()`.  It may indeed be `ResizeQuantumMemory()` in which case the compiler was able to inline the call to `ResizeMagickMemory()`.  See https://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/memory_8c_source.html line 1472.

Comment: "realloc: invalid next size" means something scribbled past the end of a `malloc` block and damaged `malloc`'s internal data structures. Use `valgrind` to get a more accurate diagnosis. If you don't understand what it tells you, post the FIRST 40 lines or so of its output here (use the tiny gray "edit" link under the tags) and we can help you read it. Don't be surprised if the problem is in some *completely different* part of the code.

Comment: @AllanWind Right, that's the whole reason I'm copying to a blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [a bug](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/commit/fdab52405409fee5d7c02fe4e60d5474caa54498) in ImageMagick.

Also, exceptions should apparently be dynamically allocated:

```
ExceptionInfo *exception = AcquireExceptionInfo();
```